# How to explain this counter-example of Baker-Campbell-Hausdorff formula?

Tags: matrices, lie-groups, lie-algebras

Let's consider $SL(2,R)$ group, we know the following group element cannot be represented by exponential of the element of $sl(2,R)$, traceless real $2\times2$ matrices.

$$B=\begin{pmatrix} -a & 0\\ 0 & -1/a\end{pmatrix}$$ 
where $a>1$.

For any $A$ of $sl(2,R)$, the eigenvalues $\lambda_1$ and $\lambda_2$ of $A$ are either both real or both purely imaginary.  In both cases $\lambda_1=-\lambda_2$. In the first case $e^{\lambda_1}$ and $e^{\lambda_2}$ are both real and positive, while in the second case $|e^{\lambda_1}|=|e^{\lambda_2}|=1$.

Suppose that $B=\exp(A)$ then $-a=e^{\lambda_1} $ which is impossible in this case.

In fact $$\exp[\begin{pmatrix} i\pi+\ln a & 0\\ 0 & i\pi-\ln a\end{pmatrix}]=B$$

So we see that $\begin{pmatrix} i\pi+\ln a & 0\\ 0 & i\pi-\ln a\end{pmatrix}$ do not belong to $sl(2,R)$.

However $B=\exp C.\exp D$, 
$$C=\begin{pmatrix} \ln a & 0\\ 0 & -\ln a\end{pmatrix}$$ and $$D= \begin{pmatrix} 0 & \pi\\ -\pi & 0\end{pmatrix}$$
where $C,D$ belong to $sl(2,R)$.

According to [Baker–Campbell–Hausdorff formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baker%E2%80%93Campbell%E2%80%93Hausdorff_formula), $\exp C. \exp D=\exp Z$ where $Z$ equals to the sum of $C,D$ and their commutators which still belongs to $sl(2,R)$. How to explain this paradox.

Comment: If you interpret the BCH formula literally and not as a statement about formal power series, then it only holds when $C$ and $D$ are sufficiently small.

Comment: It's the problem with the notion of "formula". Mathematic statements are made up of theorems, not of formulas. A theorem can state that some formula holds and sometimes, usually after specification of the context and possible restrictions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Wei, 1963](http://aip.scitation.org/doi/10.1063/1.1703910) has, in essence your "counterexample", but you skipped the crucial part on *convergence* in the 
[WP article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baker%E2%80%93Campbell%E2%80%93Hausdorff_formula#Questions_of_convergence) you are referencing, a bit breezily.

You might rewrite your expressions to highlight the fact that your matrix *D* is 
$$
D=\pi E ,
$$
where $E^2=-1\!\!1$, so then, singularly, 
$$
\exp D= \cos \pi  ~1\!\! 1+\sin \pi ~E = - 1\!\! 1 =\exp (i\pi 1\!\!1) ~.
$$

*D* has norm *π*, so $\ln \pi^2 > \ln 2$ , violating the popular CBH convergence criterion pretty badly.